# Transfer data between Python objects and numpy arrays?

Tags: python, numpy

I am working with images, and I am working with a list of objects of a class I've written, `Pixel(x, y)`. I am often having to perform operations like this -

```
std_dev = np.array(map(lambda x: x.std_dev, pixels))
# numpy processing on std_dev ---> new_property
for i, p in enumerate(pixels):
    p.new_property = new_property[i]
```

What is the most efficient way to "move" this data between Python objects and `numpy`? I want to keep the `Pixel` class, since I would need it for more fine-grained processing on parts of the image.

**Update #1**
Yes, `pixels` is a list of `Pixel` objects. I want to apply gaussian smoothing on a standard deviation map of the image. Every image pixel in the image has a standard deviation value associated to it. I am more interested in a general solution to the above problem rather than my specific case of Gaussian convolution.

Comment: So `pixels` is a list of `Pixel` objects?

Comment: Can you tell us more about your data, what you want to do with it, and your `Pixel` class? I want to suggest a different way of organizing your structures and methods, but it's hard without knowing more about the specific problem.

Comment: @Imran - added an update, happy to help with anything which is unclear

Answer (score 0):

You could let all your Pixels know their indices and share the same dictionary of ndarrays as a property->values map. Then use the dictionary key to access your Pixel's property and the Pixel's index to access the position within that property's array. This way your Pixels become something like pointers into those arrays. You'd have to keep the dictionary at a central location, though. For convenience I'd create a master or factory class.
Something like this:

```
class Pixel(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, properties):
        # _properties has to be assigned first!
        self._properties = properties
        self._x = x
        self._y = y

    def __getattribute__(self, attr):
        try:
            return super().__getattribute__(attr)
        except AttributeError:
            return self._properties[attr][self._x, self._y]

    def __setattr__(self, attr, value):
        if attr != '_properties' and attr in self._properties:
            self._properties[attr][self._x, self._y] = value
        else:
            super().__setattr__(attr, value)

class Pixelmaster(object):

    def __init__(self, width, height):
        self.properties = dict()
        self.pixels = np.array([[Pixel(x, y, self.properties) for y in range(height)] for x in range(width)])

    def setProperty(self, prop, value):
        if value.shape != self.pixels.shape:
            raise ValueError('Value has wrong shape %s, should have %s!' % (value.shape, self.pixels.shape))
        self.properties[prop] = value
        return value

    def newProperty(self, prop, dtype=float):
        return self.setProperty(prop, np.empty_like(self.pixels, dtype=dtype))

    def getProperty(self, prop):
        return self.properties[prop]
```

With this you can do stuff like:

```
master = Pixelmaster(100,100)
# get pixel at position 0, 0
p = master.pixels[0, 0]

# create a new property
master.setProperty('std',np.random.rand(100,100))

print(p.std)

# reassign the pixel's value
p.std = 5

# value is updated at the master...
print(master.properties['std'][0,0])

# ...as well as the pixel itself
print(p.std)
```

Output:

```
0.6587814533631399
5.0
5.0
```

I think you know where to go from here.

Comment: This code is for python3 by the way. If you're using python2 you'll have to change `super()` to `super(Pixel, self)`.